# toggle button angularjs directive doesn't change state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My directive toggle button doesn't take ng-change attribute when i inject it into widget.

Directive is:

```
// @ngInject
exports.abToggleButton = function($parse) {

    function templateFn() {
        return '<div class="ab-component-toggle-button">' +
            '<label>' +
            '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="ngModel" ng-change="scope.changed">' +
            '<strong></strong>' +
            '</label>' +
            '</div>';
    }

    function linkFn(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.changed = function () {
            scope.$emit('ab-component-toggle-button.changed', { id: scope.id, enabled: scope.ngModel});
        };
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            id: '=',
            ngModel: '=',
            change: '&'
        },
        link: linkFn,
        template: templateFn
    };
};
```

in html tag is:

```
<ab-toggle-button class="col-lg-3" ng-model="limit.selected" ng-change="ctrl.checkChangesState"></ab-toggle-button>
```

in my controller function is:

```
ctrl.checkChangesState = function () {
        console.log('test')
    };
```

so when i change state of toggle button. ng-change doesn't work. Whats may be a problem? Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but perhaps your directive inputs:

> change: '&',

should become

> ng-change : '='

since your use of directive is not using change=, but ng-change ?

Comment: i changed ng-change to change: '='. It started to work. Thank you, Carl!